# Visualforce report does not fit in dashboard

Tags: visualforce, reporting

I have visualforce pageblock table and I want to add it in the dashboard. When I add it as visualforce, it does not fit in the dashboard. Is there any way I can make it fit?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't fit?

Comment: As you can see in the image, the opportunity Stage at the right side is not fit.

Comment: You can set height or add scroll bar in home page component